# How to set/get/return parameters from dynamic executed query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @T INT
EXEC('SELECT @T = count(user_id) FROM ( .. .. .. )')
PRINT @T
```

I guess the example is sufficient to explain what i am trying to do, i create dynamic query and want to access its count outside the exec statement.

I am using SQL 2000. How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933299(SQL.80).aspx) which allows you to pass parameters in and out.
Main thing other than the solution below, is make sure you do really need dynamic SQL.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @T INTEGER
SET @SQL = 'SELECT @T = COUNT(user_id) FROM ......'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@T INTEGER OUT', @T OUT

PRINT @T
```